# LaTeX starts the new line at different points

Tags: errors

```
We need to minimize: $z=\sum_{i=1}^{15}x_i$ \\\\\\\\

Subject to:\\\\

$x_{door,1}+x_{door,4}+x_{room,A \, \geq \, 2}$ (Room $A$)
\\\\

$x_{door,3}+x_{door,8}+x_{room,B} \, \geq \, 1 $ (room B)
```

So i have this in latex. The problem is that latex starts the line after `\\` at different points so the sentences are not perfectly aligned vertically. After the first two `\\` latex starts left from where it started the 'we need' sentence and after `subject to:\\` it starts right from where it started the 'subject to' sentence?? Please help, thanks in advance.

edit: 
also, the 2 from the (room A) sentence is smaller than the 1 from then next sentence for some reason.

Comment: remove all the `\\ ` you should almost never have a forced newline in a latex document.

Comment: Yes but i need all the constraints of the minimize equation below eachother so i have to in this case.

Comment: No, you never need to use `\\ ` in that way.

Comment: David is far superior to me (and almost everyone else) when it comes to understanding (La)TeX but I truely believe that my approach is better in this particular case.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg yes probably I think you made a better guess of the intended meaning (this a better layout). (although I wouldn't have suggested active `|` especially to beginner)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The code in mention was suggested by Morten Høgholm years ago (according to [daleif](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)'s Danish [LaTeX manual](http://data.imf.au.dk/system/latex/bog/version3/beta/ltxb-2011-09-13-20-10.pdf#page=295)).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg yes well Morten wasn't a beginner (ever:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should hardly ever need to use `\\` and *never* use it before a blank line (end of paragraph). Also don't use math italic for words such as `room`.

I wasn't sure of the intended layout, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

We need to minimize:
\[z=\sum_{i=1}^{15}x_i\]
Subject to:
\begin{gather*}
x_{\mathrm{door},1}+x_{\mathrm{door},4}+x_{\mathrm{room},A \, \geq \, 2} (\mathrm{Room} A)\\
x_{\mathrm{door},3}+x_{\mathrm{door},8}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% useful if a lot of upright subscripts are needed
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=\active
\protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}
\endgroup
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent We need to minimize
\begin{equation*}
  z = \sum_{i = 1}^{15} x_{i},
\end{equation*}
subject to
\begin{align*}
  x_|door~$1$| + x_|door~$4$| + x_|room~A| &\geq 2 \qquad (\textup{room~A}),\\
  x_|door~$3$| + x_|door~$8$| + x_|room~B| &\geq 1 \qquad (\textup{room~B}),\\
  x_|door~$2$| + x_|door~$3$| + x_|room~C| &\geq 1 \qquad (\textup{room~C}),\\
  x_|door~$2$| + x_|door~$1$| + x_|room~D| &\geq 1 \qquad (\textup{room~D}),\\
  x_|door~$6$| + x_|door~$7$| + x_|room~E| &\geq 1 \qquad (\textup{room~E}).
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

[image: output]